# Route params in angular 2.0.0 and 2.0.1

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Which is the easiest and proper way to get the route param(multiple) in angular 2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the router provided by angular 2. There is excellent [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) for it.
There is also an excellent [blog article](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/14/routing-in-angular-2-revisited.html) which walks you through it step by step.
Another useful [post](https://coryrylan.com/blog/introduction-to-angular-2-routing) which walks you through routing.